Combinatorics Challenge: Board tiling where no dominoes are adjacent!
Consider the following problem:

Given an $n \times n$ board, what is maximum number of dominoes you can put if no two can touch each other, i.e. no two dominoes share an edge.

After some trials I have conjectured that the answer is $$\left \lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \right \rfloor$$ The even case is easy, in each $2 \times 2$ region you can have at most one domino and such a configuration is also easy to make. The issues arise when considering odd $n$, at the beginning the bound seems to be maximal, for example look at this $7 \times 7$ board:$\hspace{6cm}$

However, I have been unable to come up with a $9\times 9$ board with $20$ dominoes, the best I have been able to do are $19$ with the following tiling:
$\hspace{3cm}$ 

https://oeis.org/A145801

The odd terms for $n\ge 5$ seem to match https://oeis.org/A263511

The problem is equivalent to finding a maximum independent set in a graph with a node for each domino and an edge for each pair of dominoes that cannot coexist.  You can solve such a problem via integer linear programming (ILP) as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to $x_i+x_j \le 1$ for each edge $(i,j)$.  I used an ILP solver to verify that your conjecture is correct for $n\in\{1,\dots,8\}$, but for $n=9$ the maximum turns out to be $19$.

Could you be more precise about how does that prove the problem? I get the idea of the graph, but I can't see how that ends the problem

But can't the problem be solved without any programming?

Probably, but I wondered whether $19$ is actually optimal, so I used a solver that I have handy to quickly find out.

Oh, okay, knowing that the answer is actually $19$ for $9\times 9$ is still helpful, thanks.
